# GTM Click Element does not fire on click

Tags: google-tag-manager, eventtrigger

I want to fire a GTM trigger based on the div the button is in.

The Tag Details show the Click Element condition is not met:
[image: Tag Details]

But the Variables on the exact same Click show the Click Element does contain 'div.website-notice':

[image]

I cannot figure it out. Please help :)

Answer (score 7):

Updated GTM Debug output is misleading. `Click Element` value is `HTMLElement` not a string so you have to use `matches CSS selector` condition instead of `contains` in your trigger.

Comment: But the `Click Element` return type is a string, I did the same mistake, think is easy to make a mistake when you debug and see the string value in the variables section.

Comment: Except then you have to match the entire thing you can't match just part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "match css selector" as contain.

The click element seems not working the same way as other built-in variables.